# Computational complexity of multiplication in a nilpotent group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, computational-complexity, nilpotent-groups

What is the computational complexity of multiplication in a [Carnot group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_group) ?

***Background:*** A Carnot group is a real nilpotent Lie group $N$ whose Lie algebra $Lie(N)$ admits a direct sum decomposition

$$Lie(N) = V_{1} + ... + V_{m}$$

such that $[V_{i}, V_{j}] \subset V_{i+j}$ if $i+j \leq m$, otherwise 
$[V_{i} , V_{j}] = 0$.

Moreover, it is required that $V_{1}$ generates the whole Lie algebra $Lie(N)$.

***Detailed question:*** What is the computational complexity of multiplication in $N$, as a function of $m$, $dim V_{1}$, ... , $dim V_{m}$?

More background:

1. "Computational complexity" means giving   an estimate for the running time of an algorithm for performing the multiplication operation. I am looking for nontrivial estimates, better than, for example, the one coming from matrix multiplication. Exponentiation and logarithms are not taken into account (one variant of thinking is to use BCH formula for multiplication, with a finite number of terms due to nilpotency, other variant would be to use the remark from example 2.4 below and think about multiplication as matrix multiplication).
2. Examples of Carnot groups:

   2.1. When  m=1, this is a real vector space and the multiplication operation is just addition of vectors (thus the multiplication operation is the one of the addition of vectors, much less than matrix multiplication).

   2.2. When m=2, the simplest example is the Heisenberg group

   2.3. The group of invertible, $n \times n$ upper triangular matrices, has   $m=n−1$, $dim V_{i} = n-i$. Is there any better estimate than $n^{3}$ in this case? (I think so, but cannot find a reference to an answer.)

   2.4. Any Carnot group can be seen as a subgroup of the group from example 2.3.

   2.5. Carnot groups appear as metric tangent spaces for sub-riemannian, manifolds, see link in the question. As such, they are a kind of noncommutative vector spaces, with the "trivial" exception when they are commutative, like in the case of riemannian manifolds, when the tangent space is like in example 2.1 
   (other "simple" example being the metric contact manifolds, with the tangent space like in 2.2).

Comment: can you clarify please  how do you measure the complexity and what is input and output. Otherwise, if it realized a matrix group - multiplication is multiplication of matrices, so complexity is N^3, where N is size of faithful representation, which i think (not sure ) exists by Ado theorem + exponentiation

Comment: PS what are examples  of Carnot groups to keep in mind ?


Comment: Computational complexity as an estimate for the running time of an algorithm for performing the multiplication. 

Examples of Carnot groups: 

1. - m=1, this is a real vector space and the multiplication operation is just addition of vectors. 

2. - m=2, the simplest example is the Heisenberg group

3. - the group of invertible, $n \times n$ upper triangular matrices, has $m=n-1$, $dim V_{i}$ = n-i$. 

4. - any Carnot group can be seen as a subgroup of the group from example 3. 

5. - Carnot groups appear as metric tangent spaces for sub-riemannian, manifolds, see link in the question. 

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but then I do not quite understand why asnwer N^3 is not satisfactory ? just multiply matrices...


Comment: Because for $m=1$, when multiplication is just addition, the estimate $N^{3}$ is very bad. What more can be said for these groups, that is the question. 

Comment: Okay, I see, may be you can insert this in question to clarify it. Also complexity depends on format of input and output and would you allow exponents and logs and other funcs and how would you count there complexity.  Do I understand correctly that you mean that input is are just matrices representing the elements of the group ? But not elements of Lie ALGebra representing logs of them ? 

Comment: Thanks for all questions! First, any type of estimate would do, provided that it gives a kind of interpolation between the addition (the commutative case, $m=1$) and pure matrix multiplication (like in example 3). Btw, I suspect that even in the case of example 3, there should be a much better estimate than $N^{3}$ for multiplication of upper triangular matrices. Secondly, in case of Carnot groups it is customary to take exponential  equate to identity, or otherwise just use the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula (which is a finite sum because of the nilpotency). 

Comment: Henry Cohn is active on MO and he is expert in fast matrix multiplication and group theoretic methods for it, you might try to notify him - to do this write some comment under any question/answer

Comment: The exponent for multiplication of upper triangular matrices is the same as that for full matrix multiplication.  Specifically, you can reduce $n \times n$ matrix multiplication to the $3n \times 3n$ upper triangular case.  (Use nine $n \times n$ blocks, with identity matrices on the diagonal and a zero matrix in the upper right corner.)  So for that case the best exponent that's known is 2.373, the same as for the general case.  I'm not sure what the best trade-off one can prove is, as one transitions from vector addition to matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What about the Heisenberg group $H(n) = R^{n} \times R^{n} \times R$? It has $m=2$. 

Comment: Actually, if anybody cares, here is explained the motivation for the question: 
http://chorasimilarity.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/is-there-a-positional-numeral-system-for-carnot-groups/

Comment: Doesn't multiplication in the Heisenberg group amount to two vector additions, one inner product, and a couple of scalar additions?  (In which case it can be done in linear time.)  Maybe I am thinking of a different Heisenberg group.

Comment: You are right, I was hoping I missed something, that already for the Heisenberg group there is a difference. 

Comment: Dear Henry, after more thinking, I don't believe that "you can reduce n×n matrix multiplication to the 3n×3n upper triangular case. (Use nine n×n blocks, with identity matrices on the diagonal and a zero matrix in the upper right corner.)" There is something wrong there, are you saying that there is an injective morphism from $GL(n)$ to the group of $3n \times 3n$ upper triangular matrices? 

Comment: The reduction is not a homomorphism.  Suppose $A$ and $B$ are any $n \times n$ matrices (not necessarily invertible), and define $3n \times 3n$ matrices $A'$ and $B'$ as follows.  Both are the identity matrix, except for one $n \times n$ block.  Specifically, $A'$ has $A$ as the middle top $n \times n$ block, and $B'$ has $B$ as the middle right $n \times n$ block.  Then $A'B'$ has $AB$ as its upper right block.  These larger matrices are upper triangular, so if you can efficiently multiply upper triangular matrices, then you can efficiently multiply arbitrary matrices (of one third the size).

Comment: Thanks! Interesting that transformations of $A$ and $B$ into $3n \times 3n$ matrices are different! 

Comment: If a Lie algebra is given to you not as matrices but just by generators and relations, then first translating it into matrices may be prohibitively expensive. The current best upper bounds on the faithful representation you get from Ado's Theorem are horrible from the complexity perspective (I believe it's something like $n^c$ for Lie algebras of nilpotency class $c$ - since the nilpotency class can be as large as $n-1$ in general, this is pretty huge).