# Fastest way for certain rectangle matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity, matrix-analysis, algebraic-complexity

I have $2$ matrices over $\mathbb{N}$, from the size $n \times \sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt{n} \times n$. I would like to find an efficient way to multiply them. By efficient, I mean better than $n^{2.5}$, preferably as smaller as possible.

I came across a paper: [Faster Algorithms for Rectangular Matrix Multiplication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1111), but it refers to cases where we have a matrix of $n\times n^\alpha$ and $\alpha<0.3$, and in my case $\alpha = 0.5$.

I am wondering what are currently known approaches for this?

Comment: doesn't figure 1 from that paper answer your question? (so you can do better than $n^{2.046681}$).

Comment: Do you need a practical algorithm (i.e. are you going to actually run it) or are you after theoretical / asymptotic results? The gap between these is rather wide in matrix multiplication.

Comment: And a more recent paper by Le Gall and Urrutia claims 2.044183 https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611975031.67

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear from the question whether you are after theoretical or practical algorithms.

For **theoretical** results, [Le Gall and Urrutia (2018)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611975031.67), mentioned in Shannon Starr's comment, is probably the current record. (From quick browsing of the many works that cite them, I did not spot any works that would seem to improve this aspect.) Their Table 3 claims exponent $2.044183$ when the inner dimension is $n^{0.5}$.

For **practical** results, there exist implementations of Strassen-like algorithms for square matrix multiplication. (Use the search word "practical".) You could start from the answers to the MO question [How fast can we *really* multiply matrices?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101531/how-fast-can-we-really-multiply-matrices), where they in particular cite Huang's 2018 dissertation [Practical fast matrix multiplication algorithms](https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/handle/2152/69013).

As a very crude example: If you have a practical Strassen-like implementation that does $n\times n$ square multiplication in $O(n^{2.8074})$ time, then you can split your $\langle n,\sqrt{n},n\rangle$ task into $\sqrt{n} \times \sqrt{n} = n$ square subtasks of size $\sqrt{n} \times \sqrt{n}$, each solved in $O(n^{1.4037})$ time by the practical Strassen. Your total time is then $O(n^{2.4037})$, which fits your requirement of beating $n^{2.5}$, but falls far short of the theoretical results.

Instead of square subtasks, you could play with rectangular subtasks. Benson and Ballard (2015) have performed a practical study [A Framework for Practical Parallel Fast Matrix Multiplication](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Earb/papers/fast-matmul-ppopp2015.pdf). Despite the name, they also study serial implementations. I did not find the $\sqrt{n}$ inner dimension case mentioned, but they do a constant inner dimension case $\langle n, 1600, n\rangle$ with $2000 \le n \le 12000$, see their Figure 6. They experimented with algorithms that use base cases like $\langle 4,2,4\rangle$ and others, *and outperformed* MKL (Intel's  Math Kernel Library). Note that even if your method is asymptotically superior, it is not at all trivial to outperform fine-tuned linear algebra libraries that use the classical method. One of their conclusions is:

> [F]or multiplying rectangular matrices (which occurs more frequently
> than square in practice), there is a rich space for improvements. In
> particular, fast algorithms with base cases that match the shape of
> the matrices tend to have the highest performance.